How to disable google OAuth2 granular consent?
I received a notification email, starting June 17, 2024, Google will enable granular consent, which allows OAuth users to grant or deny Google account data permissions on a more granular level to third parties. For my project, I would like to disable granular consent.
After checking Google web side, if 'enable_granular_consent' set to false, more granular Google Account permissions would be disabled for OAuth client IDs creates before 2019.
My google oauth2 client id is create in 2018. Can I understand that I can apply this rule? Can this modification ensure that granular consent is disabled after June 17, 2024?

You can't control googles authorization server if they are enabling it you can't disable it

@warren, Do you find any solution to this issue?

You can't disable granular permissions after the June 2024 rollout. You can apply for one-time extension, which gives you few more months to update your code. You should be able to find the instruction on how to apply for the one-time extension in the email you received from Google.
